# How to get width and height of the javafx.scene.text.Text control?

Tags: java, javafx

As in the subject - how one can get width and height of the `javafx.scene.text.Text` control? This question refers to an example situation, where one want to create background for the `Text` in a form of `javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle`, whose size depends on the size of `Text`.

Comment: `text.getBoundsInLocal().getWidth()` and `text.getBoundsInLocal().getHeight()` should do it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about using `Label`? This allows for backgrounds, and the size of the label depends on the text.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Label.html

Comment: I'm using `Label` currently, but I'm curious about the possibility of getting values of parameters I've mentioned in my question.

Answer (score 0):

One thing to note is that if you are doing that *before* the component is visible, then the bounds may not be correct.  I have had to handle it this way:

```
final Text text = new Text("This is my text");
text.applyCss();
//then get you height & width
```